# SPARK 1.4.0 file not found exception for truststore

Tags: java, hadoop, ssl, apache-spark, kerberos

I am using SPARK 1.4.0 with hadoop-2.6.0. I enabled ssl using **spark.ssl.enabled**. When submitting a example job getting following exception in nodemanager logs.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Spark\conf\spark.truststore (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

When i put the truststore file in some other drive (say D:) then getting below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Spark_conf\spark.truststore (The device is not ready)
```

I have mentioned the keystore and truststore location correctly. I am following [Spark configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) to setup for SSL and ACLs

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.authenticate              true
spark.acls.enable               true
spark.admin.acls                Kumar
spark.modify.acls               Kumar
spark.ui.view.acls              Kumar
spark.ssl.enabled               true
spark.ssl.enabledAlgorithms     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
spark.ssl.keyPassword           password
spark.ssl.keyStore              C:/Spark/conf/spark.keystore
spark.ssl.keyStorePassword      password
spark.ssl.protocol              TLSv1
spark.ssl.trustStore            C:/Spark/conf/spark.truststore
spark.ssl.trustStorePassword    password
```

Help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It may be a backslash problem. In the error, it shows the filepath as

```
C:\Spark\conf\spark.truststore
```

and in the configuration file you have written it as:

```
C:/Spark/conf/spark.keystore
```

Comment: Logs shows with different slash as i am using windows machine.